# Display Yes/No Drop-Down Attribute in Magento Frontend only if Yes is Selected

Tags: magento, attributes

I'm trying to display a custom yes/no product attribute only if "yes" is selected. Here's my code so far:

```
<?php $freeship = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('free_shipping_discount');
if ($freeship == "yes")
echo '<span class="free-ship">FREE SHIPPING</span>'; ?>
```

It doesn't produce errors but it doesn't display anything either.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind. I got it! I done it this way:<?php if (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId())->getFree_shipping_discount()): ?> 
  <span class="free-ship"><?php echo $this->__('FREE SHIPPING') ?></span>
  <?php endif;?>

Comment: you can also answer and accept your own question @Freejoy! See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an uppercase Yes? I would try to use var_dump($freeship) to see whether your variable returns what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php if ($_product->getFreeShippingDiscount()):?>
<span class="free-ship">FREE SHIPPING</span>            
<?php endif;?>
```